# ngrok for redis and mysql

Tags: mysql, redis, ngrok

I just build a Node.js app.

It runs on Redis and MySQL.

Is it possible to use ngrok HTTP tunnel for Redis and MySQL at the same time on the same port or a different port?

Your comment welcome

Comment: Can you explain your requirement clearly? You want to open a tunnel for Mysql and Redis? Why would you want that to be public?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Redis and MySQL on different ports, you could run two ngrok TCP tunnels, one for each service you want to expose, over one ngrok session.

In order to run multiple tunnels over one ngrok session, you'll need to use a ngrok config file.  For this use case, it might look something like this:

```
authtoken: <YOUR_NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN>
tunnels:
  redis:
    addr: 6379
    proto: tcp
  mysql:
    addr: 3306
    proto: tcp
```

More details on running multiple tunnels here: https://ngrok.com/docs#multiple-tunnels